# fetching data from multiple tables with join?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting started with JOIN and I'm trying to fetch all rows from `clasificados` and the `abrev` and `nombre` column from five of the "JOINED" tables, may be this is not possible but I've being reading about and I thought that it was.

I'm using LIMIT

I'm getting `0` as rowCount.  Anyone could guide me please?

```
$sql2 = "SELECT cl.id AS clasid,
                cl.email AS email,
                cl.tipo_anuncio AS tipo_anuncio,
                cl.reid AS reid,
                cl.rcid AS rcid,
                cl.img_1 AS img_1,                      
                cl.titulo AS titulo,
                cl.precio AS precio,
                cl.negociable AS negociable,
                cl.estado_art AS estado,
                cl.intercambio AS intercambio,
                cl.retro AS retro,
                cl.id_cat_1 AS id_cat_1,
                cl.id_subcat_1 AS id_subcat_1,
                cl.id_subcat_2 AS id_subcat_2,
                cl.clas_pass AS clasified_key,
                cl.user_activo AS user_activo,
                cl.approved_pay AS approved,
                cl.expiracion AS expiracion,
                cl.rep_email_enviado AS rep_email_sent,
                eid.abrev AS edm_abrev,
                cid.nombre AS cdm_nombre,
                negoc.nombre AS neg,
                exch.nombre AS exchangable,
                estadoTB.nombre AS estado_articulo
        FROM clasificados AS cl
            JOIN 1_ AS cat_one 
                ON cat_one.id = cl.id_cat_1 
             JOIN estados AS eid 
                ON eid.id = cl.reid
             JOIN municipios AS cid 
                ON cid.id = cl.rcid 
             JOIN negociable_tb AS negoc 
                ON negoc.id = cl.negociable
            JOIN intercambio_tb AS exch 
                ON exch.id = cl.intercambio             
             JOIN estado_articulo_tb AS estadoTB
                ON estadoTB.id = cl.estado_art
WHERE cl.user_activo = 1 AND cl.approved_pay = 1 ORDER BY cl.id DESC LIMIT $position, $items_per_group";
```

Comment: try LEFT JOIN instead

Comment: I've tryed that, same result.

Comment: is it possible to provide your table structure?

Comment: Show us your table schema and run the above query in Sql Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/  so it will be easy for us to understand and i think before that you will find the solution for the error yourself

Comment: Table 'clasificados' structure is the same as showned in the same order, the only difference is that in the actual table I have more 'img_2,3,4...' columns.  Tables JOINED are the same id, nombre. Was that what you need to know @user27_4 ?

Comment: I'm sorry @M0rtiis I was wrong, I've tried your suggestion one more time and vuala!. Many many thanks .

Comment: And thanks to the guys trying to help.